# How to improve JSON Response Time in Wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I'm using WP-Cache Rest API but still i feel my API is slow. around 3.38s.
Tried Caching plugin and WP-cache. how can i improve the API response time.
The API I have implemented is not default API it is custom Endpoint API.